# How replicate this setup from NPM to PNPM (package.json in subdirs)

Tags: npm, pnpm

In my current codebase I have a structure and setup something like this:

```
root
- package.json
- subdir
    - package.json
    - subsubdir
        - package.json
```

`root/package.json:`

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "subdir": "file:subdir"
    }
}
```

`root/subdir/package.json:`

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "subsubdir": "file:subsubdir"
    }
}
```

When I run `npm install` on root directory, NPM installs all dependencies from all three `package.json` files and hoists them into `root/node_modules`.

How do I replicate this behavior in PNPM? I've tried `pnmp install -r` but, that just installs subdir dependencies into their own nested `node_modules` folders. I've also tried `pnpm install -r --shamefully-hoist`, but that doesn't seem to work properly (a few missing deps in root/node_modules).